# Running Keras python script through java results in sudden stop mid-script

Tags: java, python, tensorflow, keras

I have a script `predict_cnn.py` that takes an Image as Input and prints the prediction of that Image using an already trained keras model. The script works when run in console, now I want to run the script from a Java class to use its Output. However, when I try to read the Output of said script through Java, it simply stops during the loading of the keras model.

I'm using `python3.7`, `keras2.2.4`, `tensorflow1.14` and `opencv-contrib-python 4.1.0.25` for my python Project and plain Java11 for the Java Project.
I've tested passing simple "Hello World" python scripts to my Java class, as well as scripts that had multiple Input Arguments and that loaded the keras model/label binarizer with prints afterwards, all of those Tests surprisingly worked. I really don't understand why it doesn't work for `predict_cnn.py`.

Here's the Python script that prints the keras prediction to console:

```
    ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    ap.add_argument("-i", "--image", required=True, help="Path to input image")
    ap.add_argument("-m", "--model", default="output\invoice_cnn_250_ADD100-    BS256.model", help="Path to trained Keras model")
    ap.add_argument("-lb", "--label-bin", default="output\invoice_cnn_lb_250_Add100-BS256.pickle", help="Path to input label Binarizer")
    args = vars(ap.parse_args())
    print("Args used:"+args.__str__())

    # load input image and resize it to the target spatial dimensions
    print("[INFO] reading image...")
    image = cv2.imread(args["image"])
    output = image.copy()
    image = cv2.resize(image, (64, 64))

    # scale the pixel values to [0, 1]
    print("[INFO] processing image...")
    image = image.astype("float") / 255.0
    image = image.reshape((1, image.shape[0], image.shape[1],
                       image.shape[2]))

    print("[INFO] loading network and label binarizer...")
    model = load_model(args["model"])
    lb = pickle.loads(open(args["label_bin"], "rb").read())

    print("[INFO] predict image...")
    pred = model.predict(image)

    print("[INFO] process prediction...")
    i = pred.argmax(axis=1)[0]
    label = lb.classes_[i]

    print("[INFO] prediction complete")
    result = pred[0][i] * 100
    print(label + "|" + result.__str__())
```

And here's the Problem Java class that reads script output:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        // set up the command and parameter
        String pythonScriptPath = "PATH/TO/predict_cnn.py";
        String[] cmd = new String[2];
        cmd[0] = "python3.7";
        cmd[1] = pythonScriptPath;

        // create runtime to execute external command
        Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
        Process pr = rt.exec(cmd);

        // retrieve output from python script
        BufferedReader bfr = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(pr.getInputStream()));
        String line = "";
        while((line = bfr.readLine()) != null) {
        // display each output line form python script
            System.out.println(line);
        }
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(cmd));
    }
```

Expected Output is the Output I get from running the script in console:

```
    Args used:{'image': 'img\\leftover\\invoice\\i0.jpg', 'model': 'output\\invoice_cnn_250_ADD100-BS256.model', 'label_bin': 'output\\invoice_cnn_lb_250_Add100-BS256.pickle'}
    [INFO] reading image...
    [INFO] processing image...
    [INFO] loading network and label binarizer...
    [INFO] predict image...
    [INFO] process prediction...
    [INFO] prediction complete
    invoice|88.56740593910217
```

But if I run it through Java the process simply stops in the middle.

```
    Args used:    {'image': 'img\\leftover\\invoice\\i0.jpg', 'model': 'output\\invoice_cnn_250_ADD100-BS256.model', 'label_bin': 'output\\invoice_cnn_lb_250_Add100-BS256.pickle'}
    [INFO] reading image...
    [INFO] processing image...
    [INFO] loading network and label binarizer…

    Process finished with exit code 0
```

I repeat, loading the keras model and binarizer in other python scripts worked, so I'm really confused why it stops at this Point.

I tried running the same Code on a friend's pc, but he couldn't even get the Images to be read. The Tests worked tho. Another friend got the same Output as me, but the process just kept on running…

I could really need some help. Thanks.

Comment: any updates on this?